# Sql server get result of one month before

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm,-1, getdate())
select count(status)  from [full]
where (date_reception> @StartDate and status = 'OPEN')
```

I need to get result of one month before now , for example we are in 2015-03-19 i need to get result from 2015-02-19 till now.
When i try query above i get as result (4412) and when i try (where date_reception >'2015-02-19') i get (5638)

Comment: It is due to time component in getdate(). While '2015-02-19' takes records from 00:00 hour of the day. You must fetch only date from getdate() exclude time and then subtract 1 month.

Comment: That was the answer may be next that would be better to write your own comment so as to get votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time component of the date is not to be considered, try the following code. If it is, your current code seems accurate.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @currentDate date
set @currentDate = GETDATE()
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm,-1, @currentDate))
select count(status)  from [full]
where (date_reception> @StartDate and status = 'OPEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
WHERE date_reception BETWEEN  DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(GETDATE())
```

Comment: `BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()`

Comment: When i try this i get as result (4412) and when i try (where date_reception >'2015-02-19') i get (5638)